# Setting Scenario Endpoints

Tags: soap, citrus-framework

I am having problems setting an endpoint URI in a scenario for the Citrus Simulator.  Here is how I am trying to build my scenario:

```
@Override
public void run(ScenarioDesigner scenario) {
  scenario
      .soap()
      .receive().endpoint("{http://www.sikorsoftware.com/lov/schemas}LOVRequest")
      .payload("<ns2:LOVRequest xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.sikorsoftware.com/lov/schemas\"><ns2:id>123456</ns2:id></ns2:LOVRequest>");

  scenario
      .soap()
      .send()
      .payload("<LOVResponse xmlns=\"http://www.sikorsoftware.com/lov/schemas\">" +
                  "Hi there!" +
               "</LOVResponse>");
}
```

But I keep getting this message when I try to send a soap message:

> o.s.ws.server.EndpointNotFound           : No endpoint mapping found
>   for [SaajSoapMessage
>   {http://www.sikorsoftware.com/lov/schemas}LOVRequest]

What am I doing wrong.  Should I be setting up my endpoints a different way?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint is always a reference to a Citrus Spring bean component, in particular the component id that is used to add the component to the Spring application context.

In addition to that the scenario endpoint is automatically referenced when using the scenario designer instance. So in case you want to receive the scenario triggering message you do not need any endpoint reference.

When your scenario is not called this is because of some other issue in your setup. Maybe the incoming request does not map to your scenario definition.

Comment: The problem was the name of my scenario!  I just thought it was a descriptive,  it works now.  Thank you.